# Querying special characters

Tags: query, ms-access, character-set

I work with language with special characters (example: e -> é). I have a query with a `LIKE` but when I search a word with special char and my query doesn't have the special char, I don't get the results I expect:

```
select * from a where name like '%e%'
```

The above returns no results when the database contains "dés". Is there a way to have this query return the desired results.

Comment: its for access query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to try something adventurous like coding in the escape sequences.

```
select * from a where name like '%' & chr$(numberforcharacter) & %'
```

Answer (score 3):

If the collation of your database is set to accent insensitive, then this should work (for most accented characters).

For example in the collation Latin1_General_CI_AS, the CS means Case Insensitive, Accent Sensitive.  You would want the collation to be **Latin1_General_CI_AI** which means Case Insensitive, *Accent Insensitive*

Be warned though, that not all "accented" characters are created equally, but for spanish and french searches I found things work out as expected.

Answer (score -1):

I finally replace special char that I know by a %